# Making a local copy of this pointer in C++

Tags: c++

Is it possible to make a local copy of 'this' pointer in a class function? The purpose is to then modify the copy and return it, without modifying 'this' itself.

The function looks like this:

```
classA classA::function() {
   classA newObject = //where I need help; 
   //modification of newObject
   return newObject;
}
```

Comment: `classA newObject = *this;`?

Comment: Do you mean a copy of the pointer, or a copy of the object that the pointer points to?

Comment: Just use `this`. Since `this` can never be modified anyway, there's no need to make a copy of it. `this = <anything>;` will never work.

Comment: @melpomene Wow I forgot all my C++. I was trying to do &this for some reason, and totally forgot that * is how you dereference a pointer. Thank you and forgive a beginner C++ programmer!

Comment: Try this: `classA newObject(this);` But check if don't override the default constructor.

Comment: @Jorge Copy construction rarely should be provided through a pointer.

Comment: @user9212993 I'm agree with you. I tested my suggestion with a class of QT (`QMainWindow`) and it implements this construction but as you said:  rarely should be provided through a pointer. Thanks by your comment.

Answer (score 6):

You can create copies from `this` as long your class provides a copy constructor by simply dereferencing the `this` pointer as needed:

```
classA classA::function() {       
   return *this;
       // ^^^^^ Simply dereference and let the compiler do the copying
}
```

Ensure your class declaration follows the [Rule of 3/5/zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)!